# A Combination of decreasing functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions, convex-analysis

I have a strictly decreasing convex function $f$ (at least over $\Bbb R^+$ ),
and the non negative numbers $a_1 , a_2$ and $b_1 , b_2$. Is the following a decreasing function ( at least on $t \in \Bbb R^+ $).

$$g(t) = f(a_1 + b_1 t) + f(a_2 + b_2 t) - f(a_1+a_2 + (b_1+b_2)t)$$

What if we assumed $a_1 \leq a_2$ and $b_1 \leq b2$.
What about its convexity ?

Here is what I have done, since we need  $g'(t)<0$:
$$f'(a_1 + b_1 t)b_1 + f'(a_2 + b_2 t) b_2- f'(a_1+a_2 + (b_1+b_2)t) (b_1+b_2)<0$$
$$\frac{f'(a_1 + b_1 t)b_1 + f'(a_2 + b_2 t) b_2}{(b_1+b_2)}< f'(a_1+a_2 + (b_1+b_2)t) $$
Which I think is related to $f'$ being concave function.
Is my conclusion correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that since $f$ is convex, $f'$ is increasing function.
Then the inequality above follows.